# Returning "yes" in one column if it contains a string in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a column `Valid Site` if a box's exam is contained within the `Exams for this Site`.

My current approach for `Valid Site` gives me inaccurate values for some reason:

```
>>> Materials_Tracking_df

+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| EXAM   | Scoring Site DBN   | Exams for this Site   | Valid Site   |
|--------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------|
| MXRC   | 04M435             | MXRC, MXRK, MXRN,     | N            |
| MXRC   | 04M435             | MXRC, MXRK, MXRN,     | N            |
| SXRK   | 03M076             | SXRK, SXRU,           | N            |
| MXRC   | 04M435             | MXRC, MXRK, MXRN,     | N            |
+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

See how for the first row, it says MXRC is `N` for `Valid Site` even though it's clearly under `Exams for this Site`.

This is the code I'm using:

```py
MaterialsTracking_df['Valid Site'] = "Y" if MaterialsTracking_df['EXAM'].to_string() in MaterialsTracking_df['Exams for this Site'].to_string() else "N"
```

Comment: Can you please show us how your data structure looks like: `MaterialsTracking_df`.
Otherwise we can't answer this question. Need to know for example: is `Exams for this Site` a tuple or a string etc.

Comment: What is the returned value currently? Where is this information coming from? How do you get the information? Please post more code so we can duplicate your results:)

Comment: Why are you using `Series.to_string()`? That's not going to do what you think it does. Try out `MaterialsTracking_df['EXAM'].to_string()` and `MaterialsTracking_df['Exams for this Site'].to_string()` in your Python console.

Comment: `MaterialsTracking_df['Valid Site'] = ["Y" if exam in exams else "N" for exam, exams in zip(MaterialsTracking_df['EXAM'], MaterialsTracking_df['Exams for this Site'])]`, provided there are no rows with N/A values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MaterialsTracking_df['Valid Site'] = "Y" if ...
```

assigns a value to **all** rows.

Use pandas.DataFrame.apply instead
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

**example** (I added another dummy row where the condition doesn't meet):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

Materials_Tracking_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
EXAM;Scoring Site DBN;Exams for this Site
MXRC;04M435;MXRC, MXRK, MXRN
MXRC;04M435;MXRC, MXRK, MXRN
SXRK;03M076;SXRK, SXRU
MXRC;04M435;MXRC, MXRK, MXRN
SXRK;04____;MXRC, MXRK, MXRN
"""), sep=';')

Materials_Tracking_df['Valid Site'] = Materials_Tracking_df.apply(
    lambda r: 'T' if r['EXAM'] in r['Exams for this Site'] else 'N'
, axis=1)
```

---

```
   EXAM Scoring Site DBN Exams for this Site Valid Site
0  MXRC           04M435    MXRC, MXRK, MXRN          T
1  MXRC           04M435    MXRC, MXRK, MXRN          T
2  SXRK           03M076          SXRK, SXRU          T
3  MXRC           04M435    MXRC, MXRK, MXRN          T
4  SXRK           04____    MXRC, MXRK, MXRN          N
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Where can I find more documentation on this syntax `r['EXAM']`, or using a single instance of a column by placing the lambda variable directly before it?

Comment: The pandas documentation is actually not very clear. If you use apply with axis=1, then you function (or lambda expression) is called for each row. you can access the columns/values of this row like a dictionary (e.g. r['EXAM']). Maybe this helps a little more: https://thispointer.com/pandas-apply-apply-a-function-to-each-row-column-in-dataframe/